# \\my.domain.com\ not accessible in windows explorer

Tags: active-directory, windows-dns

When i try accessing `\\my.domain.com\`, Windows Explorer suggests me i check my spelling, but when i try `\\servername\`, it works. Also, `nslookup my.domain.com` and `nslookup servername` resolve to the same ip addresses. What could possibly cause this?

UPDATE: the machine i'm experiencing this on is a primary domain controller. `\\my.domain.com\` works properly on other members of the domain, but i need it on the domain controller as well, because without it group policy won't work. `my.domain.com` is a domain, not a specific machine. `net view \\my.domain.com\` gives me this:

```
C:\>net view \\my.domain.com\
System error 123 has occurred.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: are you using the actually computer name for the DNS lookup or an Alias?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is pretty vague, but AFAIK `\\name\...` type paths are sometimes resolved via broadcast query or WINS rather than DNS.  I'm not sure how the two interact sometimes.  Try running `net view \\my.domain.com\` on the command-line and see if it gives you a more informative error?

Also, is `domain.com` the Windows domain for the machine in question or some other one in your network, or just some random DNS name?  I'm not sure, but it may matter.

[This MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=281308) may be helpful.  Specifically try the `DisableStrictNameChecking` setting if all else fails.

Comment: updated my post with some additional information

Answer (score 0):

Is this an active directory domain? 
Is the computer you're testing from member of the same domain/forest?